# how to remove overlay android

Tags: android, service, kotlin, overlay

I have created a system overlay using onCreate method of service, when I start service it creates an overlay as expected. But when I try to remove this overlay calling a service method from an activity it always give me error.

here is the code in onCreate method of service

```
  wm = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    vibrator = this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator

    imageView = ImageView(this)
    imageView!!.minimumHeight = 30
    imageView!!.minimumWidth = 700
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        imageView!!.background = getDrawable(R.drawable.round)
    }
    imageView!!.setOnClickListener(this)
    imageView!!.setOnTouchListener(this)

    val params1 = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)


    layout = LinearLayout(this)
    layout!!.layoutParams = params1
    layout!!.orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL
    layout!!.gravity = Gravity.CENTER

    layout!!.addView(imageView)

    val LAYOUT_FLAG: Int
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
    } else {
        LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE
    }

    val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LAYOUT_FLAG, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER or Gravity.BOTTOM
    params.x = 0
    params.y = 0
    wm!!.addView(layout, params)
```

Now I am trying to remove this overlay by using the following code in a method of service and then calling this method form another activity

```
       public fun removeBar(){
     wm!!.removeView(layout);
   }
```

Now I call above function of service in the MainActivity as follow

```
               mService = OverlayShowingService();
                    mService.removeBar()
```

Whenever I try to do this, I get NullPointerException..

W/System.err: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

Comment: You are creating a service object which has no correlation to the actual running service. You need to send intent to the service or bind to it to obtain proper reference.

Comment: @Pawel  Thank you for your help, As you mentioned in your comment, I was using the wrong approach and the service object itself was null. It did work after passing the intent to the service and removing the view in onStartCommand. Thanks again for your big help..